# in mysql where, cast() str_to_date() and varchar which is faster and better, and why

Tags: mysql

three examples like this:
table had 300,000 data,all three are consumption 0.3s

### cast function

```
SELECT CREATE_TIME from repay_plan 
where CREATE_TIME>cast('2019-05-31 00:00:00' as datetime)
ORDER BY REPAY_ID desc limit 10000;
```

### str_to_date function

```
SELECT CREATE_TIME from repay_plan 
where CREATE_TIME>str_to_date('2019-05-31 00:00:00','%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%S')
ORDER BY REPAY_ID desc limit 10000;
```

### varchar

```
SELECT CAST(CREATE_TIME AS char) from repay_plan 
where CREATE_TIME>'2019-05-31 00:00:00'
ORDER BY REPAY_ID desc limit 10000;
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to StackOverflow aka. "SO"
Glad to have you apart of the community!
Did you try searching SO?
[I found this for you.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8093544/1896134)
Also, Please visit our [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
as this will guide you in getting more support from us in the community.

Comment: Also, What are your `Explain Plan` on all three queries?

Answer (score 0):

Comparing the create time directly against a valid MySQL datetime literal is by far the most desirable thing to do.  Your third version basically is doing this.  Here is your third version slightly modified:

```
SELECT CREATE_TIME
FROM repay_plan 
WHERE  CREATE_TIME > '2019-05-31 00:00:00'  -- no cast or conversion necessary
ORDER BY REPAY_ID DESC
LIMIT 10000;
```

This version will be faster than the first two versions, because it avoids the unnecessary date conversion function calls.  It also leaves the `WHERE` clause *sargable*, perhaps the biggest gain, which would allow MySQL to use an index on the `CREATE_TIME` column.

Comment: can you say more detail, please? why the third version （char） need not convert ？some links is best

Comment: Please check the MySQL [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-literals.html) to learn more about date and time literals.